Installation of Tensor flow Object Detection API on CPU
I am trying to install the Tensorflow Object Detection API on local CPU . I am using python 3.11.4 and Downloaded Protobuf version 3.20.3 and added the protoc.exe file to the scripts of the virtual environment . But I am getting this error  This is my installation code
!git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git
%cd models/research/
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
python -m pip install .
!pip install tensorflow==2.15.0
!python /content/models/research/object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py

